# Двумерный динамический массив указателей (char*)

Tags: c, динамические-массивы

Можете объяснить как выделить и осовободить память для такого массива?

Я пытался так, но не уверен, что это правильно, как освободить не совсем понимаю, можете подсказать как исправить выделение и как написать освобождение памяти?

```
char*** create(int num){
    char *** temp = (char ***) malloc(num * sizeof(char **));
    for (int i=0; i < num; i++) {
        temp[i] = (char **) malloc(num * sizeof(char*));
        for (int j = 1; j < num; j++)
            temp[i][j] = (char *) malloc(num * sizeof(char*));   
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Вы словами опишите структуру данных, которую хотите создать, потому что у вас в тексте кода мусора слишком много для программы на Си.

Comment: У меня есть строка, мне нужен двумерный массив, каждый элемент которого - указатель на начало слова в строке

Comment: Классика: [`***`](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer)

Answer (score 0):

Написано почти правильно, только во вложенном `for` `j` начинает расти с 1, а должна с 0:

```
for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
```

вместо

```
for (int j = 1; j < num; j++)
```

Освобождать надо в обратном порядке: сначала вложенные-вложенные массивы, потом вложенные массивы, потом основной массив:

```
void free_3d(char ***array3d, int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++)
            free(array3d[i][j]);

        free(array3d[i]);
    }

    free(array3d);
}
```

Comment: Освобождение памяти работает некорректно: выходит с ошибкой 1 (работаю под NetBeans)

Comment: `j` должно начинаться с того же места, где оно начиналось в `create()`.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, как уже указано в ответе @Mark Shevchenko, наблюдается какая-то ерунда с диапазоном индексов `j`. Умышленно ли это сделано или это ошибка - известно только вам.

Во-вторых, бросаются в глаза уродливые повторные упоминания имен типов в `malloc` и сразу же заметна очевидная ошибка

```
temp[i][j] = (char *) malloc(num * sizeof(char*));
```

На этом уровне, по идее, должен выделяться массив `char`. С чего бы это вдруг под `sizeof` здесь оказался `char *`?

В-третьих, что это вообще за уровень выделения памяти? В вопросе у вас ясно написано, что вам нужен двумерный массив `char *`. А в коде у вас явно идет выделение памяти третьего уровня, то есть создается трехмерный массив `char`. Так что именно вам было нужно?